# Implementing gradient optimization methods for non-linear functionals

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, finite-element-method, conjugate-gradient, p-laplacian

I'm trying to write a code solving the Dirichlet boundary problem for $p$-Laplacian on an arbitrary planar domain $\Omega$:
$$\begin{cases}
-\Delta_p (u) = f \text{ on } \Omega, \\
u\big|_{\partial \Omega} \equiv 0
\end{cases} $$
using finite-elements method. I rely on classical formulation by Barret, Liu 1993: https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1993-61-204/S0025-5718-1993-1192966-4/S0025-5718-1993-1192966-4.pdf
The variational formulation proposed there is as follows: given a finite-element continuous piecewise-linear basis functions, minimize
$$ J(u) = \frac{1}{p} \int_{\Omega} |\nabla u|^p \: d\Omega - \int_{\Omega} fv \: d\Omega $$
The authors used conjugated gradient method for their calculations. Due to my lack of experience (I've not studied non-linear optimization yet), I'm stuck with determining what exactly I should take as $\nabla J$. There's an explicit expression for $J$'s Gateaux derivative:
$$ J'(u)(v) = \int_{\Omega} |\nabla u|^{p-2} \langle \nabla u, \nabla v \rangle \: d\Omega - \int_{\Omega} fv \: d\Omega $$
so, by the analogy with $\mathbb{R}^n$, where a gradient is just a vector of directional derivatives along coordinate directions, I've thought maybe I should just compute $J'(u)$ along my finite-element basis functions directions: $\nabla J(u) = \langle J'(u)(\varphi_1), \dots, J'(u)(\varphi_N)\rangle$, but that sounds completely random and theoretically weird. At the other side, using linearity of my basis, I can express $J\big(\sum \lambda_i \varphi_i\big)$ as a simple function of $(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_N)$, equal something like
$$\bigg[\sum_{i=1}^{K(\Delta)} \lambda_{\Delta_i}^{2}(a_{\Delta_i}^2 + b_{\Delta_i}^2)\bigg]^{p/2} \cdot ||\Delta||$$
at each triangular mesh element $\Delta$, so one can easily get $\frac{\partial J}{\partial \lambda_i}$ for each $\lambda_i$. I've also came across some Riesz representation-related definitions (a gradient is the Riesz representation of $J'$), but I have no idea what that means technically.

Could someone give me a clue what is the right way to compute $\nabla J$? I would be also very greatful for some reading recommendatons. Thank you!

Comment: Pretty much every method you proposed can be used, some work better than others. Even the ones that are theoretically weird, whatever works on the numerical end is good to use. You could check out this [thesis](https://dspace.vsb.cz/bitstream/handle/10084/151358/BAI0012_FEI_P1807_1103V036_2023.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) that explores the approaches you described, although in a bit more special setting.

Comment: Wow thank you very much!